# Big O with independent nested loops

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Still trying to grasp Big O complexity.

I have this loop:

```
t:=0
for (i:=1;i<n+1;i++)
    for (j:=1;j<n+1;j++)
        t:=t+i+j;
```

([Also shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwJag.png))

If the nested loop depends on the outer loop I believe it would be O(n^2). I think each loop is O(n). Since they don't depend on each other, does that mean this algorithm is O(n), or would it still be O(n^2) because of each loop?

The outer loop goes from 1 to n+1... so O(n)... and so does the nested loop... so O(n*n)?

Comment: Whether inner loop "depends" on outer or not, if it is nested, it is still O(n*n) = O(n²).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer loop makes *N* iterations. For the every outer loop iteration inner loop makes *N* iterations. So the total number of iterations is *N ^ 2*.

The complexity is *O(N ^ 2)*, not *O(N)*.

Answer (score 0):

Inner loop runs n times. Outer loop also runs n times. So we have n outer loops multiplied by n inner loops and both loops add up to O(n*n).

Answer (score 0):

Time Complexity of this could be any of O(n^2),O(n^3),O(n^4) and so on. But because we choose "CEIL" minimum of all above values that's why complexity is still O(n^2).